# Verifying proof for the following power set.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am unsure if my proof for this is correct. Need verification, please!

QUESTION: Show that the condition A = B is not a necessary one for $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ by finding examples of sets A and B such that $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ but $A \ne B.$

SOLUTION:
Let A = {1,2} , B={1}

$P(A)$ = {{1},{2},{1,2}, $\varnothing$}

$P(B)$ = {$\varnothing$ , {1}}

$P(A)\cup P(B)$ = {$\varnothing$ , {1}, {2}, {1,2}}

$A \cup B$ = {1,2}

$P(A\cup B)$ = {$\varnothing$, {1}, {2}, {1,2}}.

Thus, $P(A\cup B)$ = $P(A) \cup P(B).$ However, $A \ne B$.

Comment: This is correct. :)

Comment: @bengraham12 I'm going to vote to close this question, because the answer to this question is mentioned as a comment in your previous question.

Comment: @DonThousand Sorry im new to this, I thought the question disappeared lol sorry! I hope this does not mean I am banned or something

Comment: It does not. It simply closes this question. Edit: You've asked 4 nearly identical questions in the last 24 hours. This is starting to be a bit concerning

Comment: @DonThousand They are similar but hardly. There have been subtle variances in my proofs. But thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @DonThousand Also I am simply asking to verify my proof. Its not like I am seeking full on answers lol

Comment: @bengraham12 Proof verification is fine, the issue is, that the way you are currently using the site is becoming somewhat spammy, especially as users have provided feedback on this problem on previous posts.

Comment: @DonThousand fair enough. Again, I apologize for inconveniencing you.

Comment: No problem! I'm quite happy that you are putting in work into your questions, that's more than can be said about others. But, for the sake of maintaining a clean site, such steps are necessary.

Comment: @DonThousand thanks. I just saw you're a student at UChi, that is my dream school for grad school. I am currently a double major, math & econ, with a minor in CS. That is so cool that you go there. Sorry if it sounds like im sucking up but thats awesome that you go there.

Comment: @bengraham12 Haha thanks, pm me if you have questions.